# How to allow no file extensions access using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

In order to avoid user's access to the folder. I set the following code to .htaccess file

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch ".*\.(css|js|php)$"> 
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

User can open .css .js .php files only.

but I would like to hide .php extensions and allow the users access no file extensions.

so I using following code to hide extensions with .php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/\s?] [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea how to make users allow no file extensions access using .htaccess?

Thank you very much

Comment: instead using htaccess, you also can forward every single thing (url) to a php is much more secure. Then build a function with a header tag to determine the file type. If you want using this flow I can send to you as an answer. The url will looks like: https://www.example.com/assets/example.js (which it is written in php)

Comment: @Mystogan Why should that be "much more secure"?

Comment: I would suggest to explicitly check if the request targets a folder by means of a `RewriteCond` and rewrite that to a 403. Then you can rewrite the rest of the requests as you like.